# Image rotation cutting edge on drawrect

Tags: objective-c, image, rotation, drawing, image-rotation

I am rotating a view and masking the shape of the view using `CAShapeLayer`.  I have view frame and bezier path of drawing shape, it is cutting the edges of my shape when i draw it using `CGContext` to make its sized shape. Here is my code:

```
- (UIImage*) crop:(UIImage*)image rect:(CGRect)rect  withRadian:(CGFloat)radian
{
    float degree = RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(radian);
    //    // translated rectangle for drawing sub image
   // float degree1 = fabsf(degree);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    // translated rectangle for drawing sub image

     CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(-rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    // grab image
    UIImage* croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return croppedImage;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what the problem is?

Comment: anyone kindly give suggestion ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve or why the current code doesn't work. Can you perhaps share a screenshot of the result you're getting now, and a mockup of what you want to have happen?

Comment: i am trying to crop image its croping but cut edges of cropped image.

Comment: problem with this code if it centerlize image draw in rect then image edge cut and if i have some space in x and y then image not centerlize.

Comment: kindly give me suggestion what i need to do to avoid this problem.